# Compartir storage entre dos proyectos Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, storage

Hola buenas tardes hace algún tiempo hice algo parecido pero ahora parece no funcionar. Tengo dos proyectos Laravel 5.8. Una es la web y otro es una Intranet desde donde controlo varios proyectos. Entonces desde la Intranet es donde inserto noticias en la base de datos del proyecto web. Lo que hice fue una vez tengo mi enlace simbolico en mi intranet, compartirlo con el segundo proyecto para que pueda utilizarlas.

```
ln -s /var/www/intraPruebas/storage /var/www/Depildiodo/public/storage
```

Este es el comando que utilizo en la terminal, y al entrar haciendo `cd/Depildiodo/public/storage/` entro sin problemas. El problema es en la web que me devuelve `error 404` en la carga de imagenes.

En el archivo `.conf`:

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Y en la vista imprimo así las imagenes, como lo vengo haciendo normalmente:

```
background: url('{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}
```

La ruta que me devuelve el error es la siguiente:

```
https://domino.com/storage/photos/1/Blog/blog3.jpg
```

¿En que estoy fallando? Hace algún tiempo lo hice con ayuda de un compañero de aquí, pero ahora no encuentro la solución

Comment: No lo había pensado aunque la otra vez no me fue necesario algo así, de todos modo lo he probado y me devuelve esto `Call to undefined function storage()` @JuanRivera

Comment: Para descartar dudas, ejecutastes el comando `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: Pues no, por que ya cree el enlace simbolico que viene del otro servicio, si hago eso no estare sustituyendo el enlace simbolico que necesito? @JuanRivera

Comment: ¿Solo las de ese dominio te dan problemas? Me causa curiosidad que no hagas en el filesystem `'url' => 'domain/path/other/storage'` y lo dejes predefinido como viene.

Comment: Hola si en la intranet no tengo problemas, claro está que el storage es de esta app. Pero lo veo muy raro que pueda acceder a el pero no lea las imagenes. Lo del domain no lo hago, por que uno es https y el de la intranet no @gaidyjg

Comment: Bueno, si haces consulta a dominios donde uno tenga https y el otro no, siempre será un dolor de cabeza resolver. Muchas veces te bloquerán consultas en ese sentido.

Comment: No entiendo que quieres decir? no puedo hacer lo del enlace simbolico?? no va a funcionar?

Comment: Estás seguro de que tu link no debería haber sido creado así? `ln -s /var/www/intraPruebas/storage/app/public /var/www/Depildiodo/public/storage` ?

Comment: Pues no lo he probado así, ahora no tengo el pc a mano, mañana lo pruebo. Pero tiene algún motivo para ser como dices @JonatanLavado ??

Comment: Hola @JonatanLavado tenias razón, claro tiene que poder leer directamente la carpeta photos. Muchas gracias, por que no publicas la solución y la marco como correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu error estaba en que la ruta de origen no era el correcto para crear el enlace simbólico.

Por defecto, el driver que [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk) utiliza para el `public disk` es el `local`, el cual almacena los archivos en `storage/app/public`.

Por lo que el comando debería ejecutarse así:

```
ln -s /var/www/intraPruebas/storage/app/public /var/www/Depildiodo/public/storage
                                   ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ
```